# Error with functions while deploying Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am getting an error when deploying my firebase function. I have sifted through this question on here and none of the solutions worked in my case. I've tried changing the spacing running the --only functions command etc.

"Function deploy had errors with the following function:
helloWorld

Here is my Index.js file

```html
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello World");
});
```

```js
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Here is my Package.json

Comment: please post code snippets as text instead of pictures. It makes it easier for other members to work on it or quote it if needed.

Comment: @beniutek thank you for this response! This is the first question asked on here so appreciate that tip.